# transform value if falsy

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm validating my DTOs with the **class-validator** package. I enabled the transformation via

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
  }),
);
```

in my main.ts file as described in the docs

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#transform-payload-objects

I have a optional configuration field in my DTO. This field should be transformed to an empty object if it doesn't exist. The transformation decorator is described here

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization#transform

I was hoping to come up with this solution:

```
export class MyDTO {
  @IsObject()
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(configuration => configuration || {})
  public configuration: object;
}
```

When I call my API route

```
@Post()
public create(@Body() myDTO: MyDTO): void {
  console.log(myDTO);
}
```

with an empty body, so without the field `configuration` my `MyDTO` instance is

```
{}
```

although I would expect it to be

```
{
    configuration: {}
}
```

What is wrong or what am I missing? I tried to debug the code and it never hits the transformation function. So the `@Transform` doesn't trigger.

---

**Update**

It seems I have to do this

```
@IsObject()
@IsOptional()
@Transform(configuration => configuration || {}) // will be used if the field exists
public configuration: object = {}; // will be used if the field doesn't exist
```

The initial value will be used if you pass in an empty body. The transformation only runs if you pass in the field but assign a value like `null` to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gonna go ahead n put this here too: why not just let typescript manage the default value with setting the value like

```js
export class MyDTO {
  @IsObject()
  @IsOptional()
  public configuration: object = {};
}
```

That way, if you get a value, great, and if it isn't there, class-transform will put the correct value there.

[Looks like there is more discussion about solutions here](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/129).

Comment: Thanks :) This works for non existing fields but when assigning `null` to it, the code breaks. I updated my question for a solution but maybe this can be improved